# Is using multiple else if statements bad practice in this instance?

Tags: java, android

I am using multiple else ifs to make the program do something depending on the currently selected values in the spinners, but I can't help but think there is a cleaner way of doing this. Any suggestions?

```
    if(spinnerinput.equals(spinnerinput2)) {
        output.setText(input.getText());
    }

    else if(spinnerinput.equals("Base 2") && spinnerinput2.equals("Base 10")) {
        String regex = "[0-1]+";

        if (input.getText().toString().matches(regex)) {
            output.setText(binaryToDecimal(input.getText().toString()));
        } else {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "Invalid characters for a binary number!";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
        }
    }

    else if(spinnerinput.equals("Base 10") && spinnerinput2.equals("Base 2")) {
        String regex = "[0-9]+";

        if(input.getText().toString().matches(regex)) {
            output.setText(decimalToBinary(input.getText().toString()));
        } else {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "Invalid characters for a decimal number!";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The `if`/`else if` part isn't a problem, but you definitely want to factor out the contents of those second two blocks into a parameterized reusable method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `if-else` is not much problem, but you can refactor your code to be minimal. Your bottom two condition-blocks only differ in `CharSequence` text. Why not convert it to a method and use same code again?

```
private void yourCurrentMethod() {

    if(spinnerinput.equals(spinnerinput2)) {
        output.setText(input.getText());
    }

    else if(spinnerinput.equals("Base 2") && spinnerinput2.equals("Base 10")) {
        String regex = "[0-1]+";
        boolean isBinary = true;
        doSomething(isBinary, "Invalid characters for a binary number!");
    }

    else if(spinnerinput.equals("Base 10") && spinnerinput2.equals("Base 2")) {
        String regex = "[0-9]+";
        boolean isBinary = false;
        doSomething(isBinary, "Invalid characters for a decimal number!");
    }
}

private void doSomething(boolean isBinary, CharSequence text){
    if(input.getText().toString().matches(regex)) {
        if(isBinary){
            output.setText(binaryToDecimal(input.getText().toString()));
        } else {
            output.setText(decimalToBinary(input.getText().toString()));
        } 
    } else {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually the code also differs in this line:         `output.setText(decimalToBinary(input.getText().toString()));`

Comment: you are right, edited the answer, but that increased one more negligible if-statement.

Comment: and of course, we don't need the booleans in `yourCurrentMethod` unless...they're needed elsewhere. Just passing them as the first argument to `doSomething` is enough.

Comment: they are just to make the code human readable. You can change it to your liking.